# Admob portrait banner smart ads - Can game be scaled when ad is put in

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, admob, scaling

I was using iads for a while on my app.  Now that they are going away I have put in admob ads.  Problem is they go over my buttons on the bottom. iAds automatically scaled the app and placed the ad in without affecting placement of anything. Is there a good way to scale the app when an admob ad is there?  That way everything can still be on screen and nothing moved or adjusted. Does admob have that functionality built in?

thanks